# How do I create a class that performs all my ActionListener functions in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

I have 2 separate classes that is used to construct separate sides of my GUI.

In one of these classes `MainGUI` has a JButton named `jb1`.
I have been trying to assign an ActionListener to this button, to make it so that when the JButton is clicked. several JLabels have their contents updated.

I have attempted the code below,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import api.jaws.Jaws;


public class Controller implements ActionListener{

    private MainGUI maingui;
    private Sharkpanel sharkPanel;
    private String sharkname;
    private static Jaws jaws =new Jaws("XyP0D75oRCGrLE78","x47ka5jmOGaJ2zvw");
    static ArrayList<String> sharknamelist=new ArrayList<String>();


     public Controller(MainGUI maingui,Sharkpanel sharkPanel){

        this.maingui = maingui;
        this.sharkPanel = sharkPanel;

        MainGUI.getSearchBtn().addActionListener(this);

        sharknamelist.addAll(jaws.getSharkNames());

        for (String s: sharknamelist){

            sharkname += s+"\t";

        }
     }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                 sharkPanel.jlz.setText("Test");

            //6 more Labels. 


        }

    }
```

However nothing happens. I had originally done `sharkPanel.jlz.setText(sharkname)`.

However nothing ever happened, I thought that it may have been because I did not properly convert the ArrayList into String. So I tested it by putting `"Test"` and nothing happens.

I have tried adding an addController method into the 2 respective GUI classes and nothing happens. Like so,

```
public void addController(Controller controller){
    control = controller;
    jb1.addActionListener(control);

}
```

But still nothing happens, I was considering using a MouseListener but I know this can be done I just don't see what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

This is all getSearchBtn does.

```
 private static JButton jb1;

  jb1=new JButton("               Search               ");

public static JButton getSearchBtn() {

    return jb1;
}
```

Comment: Do **not** use a MouseListener for this. That's not how they are intended to be used

Comment: I'm going to guess that `MainGUI.getSearchBtn()` isn't returning what you think it should.

Comment: It seems that you're relying on `static` which isn't a good idea. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I've tried doing it without the `static` but it doesn't seem to let me do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MainGUI  class`,

add this ,

```
jb1.addActionListener(new Controller(.....));
```

after button correctly initialized/instantiate

to do above changes, then after `jb1` button able to call `actionPerformed-method` of jb1..addActionListener(new Controller(.....));.

And remove,

```
MainGUI.getSearchBtn().addActionListener(this);  from Controller class.
```